# Why elasticsearch shards goes unassigned

Tags: elasticsearch

I have 2 nodes running elastic search cluster with 5 shards and 1 replica.It shows cluster health to green but suddenly it shows cluster health to yellow and I fix it by shard re-routing.
.

I wants to understand root cause of unassigned shards because when it goes to yellow state I tried telnet between both nodes on port 9300 and 9200 and connected successfully

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also faced that problem earlier and that time I went to elasticsearch logs.So based on that I fixed the issue.

So my suggestion is please go to logs and check what is the route cause of the issue.

regards

Kartheek Gummaluri